# Svelte POST request to fetch and render SVG image data

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have an endpoint which I can make a post request to, which returns data with Content-Type image/svg+xml. I am trying to use fetch in Svelte to call this endpoint. I can make the request and see that it is made, but how do I extract the svg from the response, and possibly render it in the browser?
This doesn't work

```
<script>
    let foo = '';
    let result = null;

    async function doPost() {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/build', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { Accept: 'image/svg+xml' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                formula: foo
            })
        });

        const data = await res.text();
        result = data;
    }
</script>

<input bind:value={foo} />
<button type="button" on:click={doPost}> Post it. </button>
<p>Result:</p>
<pre>
{result}
</pre>
```

I can see the following errors in the console:

Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/build due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Origin localhost:5173 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

Comment: What's the value of `result`?

Comment: it displays null after i submit the form, it doesn't change

Comment: That would mean that either `data` is `null` too or `result = data;` never happens. Add some `console.log` statements to your function to verify which parts are executed and which values you get.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read the response via [`text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) and store in a local state variable. The variable then can be inserted via [`{@html variable}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-html).

(You should be certain that the response does not contain user input or make sure that the response is sanitized first to prevent XSS attacks.)

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I tried that and it didn't work, I've updated the question

Comment: You did not. You are not using `@html`.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: If the value is `null`, the problem is probably your endpoint/how you call it. Did you set CORS headers, if this runs on a different origin? (You should have errors in the console/network info if the request fails because of it.)

Comment: I can see the following: Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/build due to access control checks. Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:5173 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

Comment: Postman is *not* a valid comparison because it has no concern for origins.

Comment: Enabling CORS fixed it.